# How to parse the Raw16 data from the package which cypress CX3 transfer for YUV formating

Tags: image, matlab, yuv, uvc

all
I use the cypress USB3.0 control chip(CX3) to transfer the image data from my sensor.
But the CX3's SDK not support the raw16 data format, and i think that the bit width  of raw16 and yuv2 are both 16 bits, so i make the sensor output raw16 data format and use the yuv2 format to transfer my raw data to the host, and i really get the data from the CX3 by the matlab or the e-cam tool which be able to preview the video stream. But of cause the color distort, because the receiver regard the data(under the UVC protocol) as the YUV data.
So my question is :

1. What's the different between the raw and yuv data order? Or another
   say, how the receiver(camera tool) treat as the yuv data and raw data?
2. How can i parse the raw data from the UVC packages which contain the
   raw data but using the yuv format to package?

Comment: The cypress tag is for https://www.cypress.io/, not what you're using it for

Comment: Please don't edit the [tag:cypress] tag back in. As mentioned, that tag represents a testing framework.